# How to run custom Symfony2 command in background

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2 enables developers to create their own command-line commands. They can be executed from command line, but also from the controller. According to official Symfony2 documentation, it can be done like that:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');

    $arguments = array(
        ...
    );

    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

}
```

But in this situation we wait for the command to finish it's execution and return the return code.

How can I, **from controller**, execute command forking it to background without waiting for it to finish execution?

In other words what would be equivalent of

```
$ nohup php app/console demo:greet &
```

Comment: We recently ran into the same issue and solved it using the [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation I don't think there is such an option: http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.html

But regarding what you are trying to achieve, I think you should use the process component instead:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if ('err' === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
});
```

And as mentioned in the documentation "if you want to be able to get some feedback in real-time, just pass an anonymous function to the run() method".

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/process.html

Comment: Without investigating the details very much, i did this using `$process->start()` instaed of `$process->run()`

Comment: Seems like run() calls start() and then wait() so in your case you are right, you should use start. [link](https://github.com/symfony/Process/blob/master/Process.php)

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation is better use start() instead run() if you want to create a background process. The process_max_time could kill your process if you create it with run()

*"Instead of using run() to execute a process, you can start() it: run() is blocking and waits for the process to finish, start() creates a background process."*

Comment: Can you elaborate on process_max_time? Google does not return any relevant results for this except your post.

Comment: @gadelat Probably meant an option in `php.ini`: [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)